# Weil reciprocity vs Artin reciprocity

Tags: hilbert-symbol, quadratic-reciprocity

This is probably an easy question for the experts:

Given two rational functions $f$, $g$ on a non-singular projective algebraic curve X (over an algebraically closed field $k$) and $p \in X$, one defines the Weil symbol $(f, g)_p$ as 
the value of $(-1)^{ab} f^a g^{-b}$ at $p$ where $a = v_p(g)$ and $b = v_p(f)$. (Here $v_p$ means order of zero/pole at $p$.)

Weil reciprocity claims that product of $(f, g)_p$ for all $p \in X$ is equal to $1$.

My question is whether the Weil symbol can be realized as a special case of the Artin symbol (for an extension of fields of rational functions)?

(Note that the ground field $k$ is not assumed to be of positive characteristic.)

Comment: Perhaps you need to assume that $\mathrm{div}(f)$ and $\mathrm{div}(g)$ are disjoint.  

Comment: Strictly speaking, the Artin symbol makes sense only for (number fields and) function fields over *finite* fields.  But there is version of Weil reciprocity for the latter, and your question would still make sense. 

Comment: The Weil symbol can be defined when $\mathrm{div}(f)$ and $\mathrm{div}(g)$ overlap. Let $\pi$ be a uniformizer at $p$ and write $f = f_0 \pi^b$ and $g = g_0 \pi^a$. Then $(f,g)_p = (-1)^{ab} f_0(p)^a g_0(p)^{-b}$. Exercise: This is independent of the choice of $\pi$.

Comment: David - doesn't this agree with what Kiumars wrote?  Since $f^ag^{-b}$ has neither a zero nor a pole at p, it can be evaluated at $p$.

Comment: Oh I see. I was thinking we evaluate $f$ and $g$ first and then plug in, but, of course, doing it in the other order makes more sense. So Kiumars' definition is right even when $\mathrm{div}(f)$ and $\mathrm{div}(g)$ do overlap, without modification. My bad.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. What I meant above is what Dustin also pointed out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Weil reciprocity actually holds for arbitrary fields $k$, not necessarily algebraically closed:  just let $x$ run over all closed points of $X$, and replace your expression for $(f,g)_x$ by its norm from $k(x)^* $ down to $k^*$.

Then the connection with Artin reciprocity occurs when $k$ is a finite field (of size say $q$), as Chandan suggests.  More precisely, if $K$ denotes the function field of $X$, then Weil reciprocity for $X$ is equivalent to Artin reciprocity for the Galois $K$-algebra $L_f = K[t]/(t^{q-1}-f)$, with Galois group $k^*$ acting by multiplication on $t$.

Even more precisely, we mean that for all $x$ in $X$ we have $(f,g)_x = Art(L_f/K)_x(g)$.  To verify this, note that since both sides have a product formula and finite modulus, by weak approximation it suffices to consider the case where $x$ is not in the support of $f$.  Then the left-hand side is the norm of $f(x)^{v_x(g)}$ and the right hand side is $Frob_x^{v_x(g)}$, so it suffices to show that $Frob_x$ is the norm of $f(x)$.  But the residue field extension is $k(x)[t]/(t^{q-1}-f(x))$, so letting $d$ denote the degree of $k(x)$ over $k$ we can calculate the Frobenius as sending $t$ to $t^{q^d} = t^{q^d-1} \cdot t = (t^{q-1})^{1+q+...+q^{d-1}} \cdot t = f(x)^{1+q+...+q^{d-1}} \cdot t = Norm(f(x)) \cdot t$, as desired.

Comment: Could you insert a few \$s (by which I don't mean American money but the symbol \$) to make your answer more easily readable ?

Comment: OK Chandan, I fancied it up.  I  also corrected some p's to q's.

Comment: It is also worth noting that, if $b | p-1$, then Artin reciprocity for $K[t]/(t^b-f)$ can be expressed in terms of the Weil symbol as well: the relation is $(f,g)_x^{(p-1)/b} = \mathrm{Art}(L_f/K)_x(g)$. In particular, if $p$ is odd, $b$ is $2$, $g$ is irreducible and $x_1$, ..., $x_n \in X$ are the zeros of $g$, then the product $\prod_{x_i} (f,g)_{x_i}^{(p-1)/b}$ is "take $f$ modulo $g$ and raise it to the $(p^{\deg g}-1)/2$ power", an expression which should be familiar from proofs of quadratic reciprocity.